# How can i add this other condition to this code?

Tags: basic, winlims

i have this subroutine that i use to make labels. for some reason i cant just make another subroutine where instead of "CGI_SAMPLE_LABEL" it uses "YCI_SAMPLE_LABEL" because of other subroutines. any suggestions on how i can add this so that it chooses either one or the other. if tried using WHERE OR but that didn't work. i edited some of the tags because LIMS basic language is also like smalltalk.

```
LabelType = "CGI_SAMPLE_LABEL"
pTableNameStr = "SAMPLE"
pLabelNameStr = "CGI_SAMPLE_LABEL"

'Breakpoint(aReason) 
NumSamples = Ubound(selectedObjects, 1)

FOR X = 1 TO NumSamples
    SampleNumber = selectedObjects[x]   
    pKeyNameArr[1] = SampleNumber 
    pNumLabelsInt = 1
    pLabelNameStr = "CGI_SAMPLE_LABEL"
    pReasonStr = "Auto Label Generation"
    pActivityStr = "Label printed for sample logged event"
    GOSUB FN_LABEL_PRINT_ALL
NEXT 'Sample

RETURN
```

Comment: This doesn't look like SQL to me.  Please tag with the actual language you are using.

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant tag and replaced it with a guessed one. You should review and tag it properly to get the correct people looking at your question

Comment: This doesn't look like any variation of BASIC that I'm familiar with

Comment: @BillHileman from the second tag added I assume it is this https://limshelp.labware.com/limsv5/V5_LIMS_Basic_1_1_nbsp__LIMS_Basic_Overv.htm

Comment: yes it's lims labware v.7 but not much has changed.

Comment: I've removed the `smalltalk` label since this doesn't look anything like Smalltalk.

Comment: You might be out of luck here as `winlims` tag only has 3 questions ever asked and 4 followers